# Linenumbering problem

Tags: tables, line-numbering

When I am using line numbering I am getting to this problem:
[image]

Basically the command for line numbering is perfectly working until page 8 from 11 of my document. It seems that from this point the document (text, pictures, tables and references) will only appear on the left column of my document. 
Do you have any suggestions how can I repair this?

Thank you!
Best regards,
Ioana.

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  more information is needed before anyone here would be able to diagnose the problem.  try to narrow it down; something seems to be happening on the second column of the last full page, or the first one-column-only page. copy your file to another name to test.  try omitting material from the earlier pages until you get just one two-column page before the problem starts.  then you can substitute large empty boxes for groups of lines (leave some lines that show the numbering).  what's left can then be used as a "minimal example" that people can work with.